# Connect to not specific database name

Tags: mysql, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to connect to database name that i given in Textfield and click open button so i can use the database name that i entered in Textfield , so i need to not specified the database name in my dbconnection class

CONN = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_NAME?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true";

```
public static Connection getConnection () throws SQLException{
    try {

        return DriverManager.getConnection(CONN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);       //Entering database connection elements (URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD).
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks for helping me ..

Comment: Can you give more details what's the problem with your code?

Comment: i have now problem with my code; but i need to create class that i can to connect to database name that i given in Textfield, in my code i need to specify the database name